# Can this insertion sort be optimized?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

Could you provide feedback for this code? For arrays of length 2, is it more efficient not to use a sorting algorithm?

```
package insertion.sort;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class InsertionSort {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArr = {-10, -5, 100, 51, 6, 50};
        insertionSort(testArr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArr));
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int j;
            for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > temp; j--)
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

By the way, I've noticed "quicksort" is spelt all as one word, but "insertion sort" is spelt as two. Is that right? Would anyone ever say "quicksort sort"?

Comment: You could consider finding out about the grammar question on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).  It doesn't really relate to the code in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Minor issues

- The word "insertion" in the method name `insertionSort` is redundant: it's already in the class name
- The Javadoc for the `main` method is pointless, it would be better to remove
- Perhaps you did it this way for the sake of an example, but the `main` method would be better in another class, not `InsertionSort` itself.

#### Generalizing

It might be good to generalize the class so that it can sort anything, not only integers. Perhaps something like this:

```
public class InsertionSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {    
    public void sort(T[] arr) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            T temp = arr[i];
            int j;
            for (j = i; j > 0 && arr[j - 1].compareTo(temp) > 0; j--) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

class InsertionSortDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] ints = {-10, -5, 100, 51, 6, 50};
        new InsertionSort<Integer>().sort(ints);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));

        String[] strings = {"hello", "there", "my", "friend"};
        new InsertionSort<String>().sort(strings);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As insertion sort is an O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, there's not much point to optimizing it.  For any input that is large enough for you to care about the performance, you would want to pick a sorting algorithm with better bounds.  Quicksort, for example, is usually closer to O(*n* log *n*).

That said, I'll point out some style issues:

- You should never omit optional braces, as you've done for the inner for-loop.  Think of it this way: anytime you omit braces, you're a contributing factor to a future coding accident.  (Apple [learned this lesson the hard way](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html); their new [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) language *requires* braces.)
- Variables can usually be named better than "temp".  Renaming `temp` to `elementToInsert`, for example, would make your code self-documenting.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see any performance issues. Stylistically, a [No Raw Loops](https://www.google.com/search?q=no%20raw%20loops&rct=j) rule mandates factoring out an inner loop into a method (`shift_right` or something like that).

Comment: I don't get raw loops. All those examples are for C++.

Comment: -1 for linking to google search